# Work of three months vs longer gap in CV

Tags: resume, employment-gaps

I have a sort of quandary here. My CV is long, no lacking of experience. I was an expat, and upon returning to my home country, I had a period of unemployment/holidays of about a year.

In the following year I had a short job/consulting gig of 3 months that did not go particularly well mainly due to personal reasons. Often in interviews I have far more trouble explaining why I was only there 3 months than explaining the year gap.

In the meanwhile I have already been continuously employed for more than 5 years, and so that gap is not already so serious.

I am considering wether it is more wise to:

- strike down the 3 months post from my CV, (and having a longer gap, 1.3 years);
- giving an white lie and saying it was just a short gig;
- saying an half-truth that it was not a fit for me;
- or telling a more interesting project came up, and I chose that. (I have a very interesting consulting project right after this one)

Whilst I personally do not have problems about explaining it was a complicated period of my life, I feel that talk does not fit in an interview.

I would be interested in knowing what do you advise.

Comment: Why would people still be asking you about a three month job 5 years ago?

Comment: Good question, but they do. People culturally here give importance to a commitment to  long-term employment.

Comment: Consulting gigs are often short...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would list it and if asked why it was only three months say it wasn't a good fit for you. Don't go in to your personal issues, but be prepared to briefly explain why it wasn't a good fit, because you might be asked.

If you're asked focus on things like skills, overqualified, underqualified, whatever you can come up with, and keep it brief as if it's unimportant. This only becomes important if you make it. Otherwise any bland explanation is fine. So no drama.

One three month job is totally understandable in that context, and it's far in the past.